# Disconnected ADO.Net mode, load from Datable to Sql Table

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have two Databases Movies(id, name) and SessionsCinema(id, SessionTime, movie, hall, price).
id - is auto increment row.

I work in ado.net Disconnected mode with ms sql database.
I want to save settings to sql table.
Changes to table "Movies" is ok, but with table "SessionsCinema" there are some errors.

```cs
//connection start
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "MYPC\SQLEXPRESS";
builder.InitialCatalog = "Cinema";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
//connection end


//Movies start
SqlCommand inscmd = new SqlCommand();
inscmd.CommandText = "Insert into Movies (name) values(@name); select id = @@IDENTITY from Movies";
inscmd.Connection = conn;
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250, "name");

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(inscmd);
adapter.InsertCommand = inscmd;
adapter.Update(Movies);
//Movies end

//SessionsCinema start
inscmd = new SqlCommand();
inscmd.CommandText = "Insert into SessionsCinema (SessionTime, movie, hall, price) values(@SessionTime, @movie, @hall, @price); select id = @@IDENTITY from SessionsCinema";
inscmd.Connection = conn;
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime,@movie,@hall,@price", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250, "SessionTime,movie,hall,price");

adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(inscmd);
adapter.InsertCommand = inscmd;
adapter.Update(SessionsCinema);
//SessionsCinema end
```

Comment: What are the errors exactly?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ','.
Must declare the scalar variable "@SessionTime"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must look at closer to `SqlParameterCollection.Add` signature.

```
//SessionsCinema start
            inscmd = new SqlCommand();
            inscmd.CommandText = "Insert into SessionsCinema (SessionTime, movie, hall, price) values(@SessionTime, @movie, @hall, @price); select id = @@IDENTITY from SessionsCinema";
            inscmd.Connection = conn;
            inscmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = SessionTime;
            inscmd.Parameters.Add("@movie", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = movie;
            inscmd.Parameters.Add("@hall", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = hall;
            inscmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = price;
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(inscmd);
            adapter.InsertCommand = inscmd;
            adapter.Update(SessionsCinema);
//SessionsCinema end
```

Comment: This won't set the value on those parameters. The last argument to `.Add()` is setting a source column.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime,@movie,@hall,@price", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250, "SessionTime,movie,hall,price");
```

You need a separate Parameters.Add() call for each of the parameters in that list. It should look something like this:

```
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = SessionTime;
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@movie", SqlDbType.Int).Value = movie;
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@hall", SqlDbType.Int).Value = hall;
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = price;
```

Also, check your parameter from your first command. It looks like you made the same mistake there.

Comment: How to write it, if (SessionTime) - string, (movie,hall,price) - int ?  
  
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250, "SessionTime");  
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@movie", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "movie");  
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@hall", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "hall");  
inscmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "price");  
  
This code is wrong.

Comment: @user2963950 You can't use `sizeof` like that.

Comment: The name price does not exist in the current context. About hall,movie, SessionTime is the same situation.

Comment: @user2963950 Where is that information stored, then?

Comment: I successfully load information from SQL tables into DataSet. Then modify tables and try to save it to SQL tables. Changes to table "Movies" - ok, changes to table "SessionTime" - badly. There is an exception - "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows." But I do not lose data in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Your first command works because it has only one parameter and you define one [`.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for it. That's ok.

But your second command has 4 parameter and you can't add 4 parameter in just one [`.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

You need to add them seperatly with [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionTime, SessionTime);
inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movie", movie);
inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hall", hall);
inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
```

Comment: Not a fan of AddWithValue(), because it forces .Net to guess at the parameter time. Sometimes .Net guesses wrong, and sometimes when that happens there are significant performance implications.

Comment: Error -The name price does not exist in the current context. About hall,movie, SessionTime is the same situation.

Comment: @user2963950 Where did you define the values that you want to insert?

Comment: I create public class, in this class there is variable of DataSet type, in this class there is a method that create some variables of DataTable type and add it to DataSet variable, then in this class there is a method that Save data from Datable to Sql Table.